# (Known) compiler bug in VC12?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug

This program, when compiled with VC12 (in Visual Studio 2013 RTM)<sup>[1]</sup> leads to a crash (in all build configurations), when really it shouldn't:

```
#include <string>

void foo(std::string const& oops = {})
{
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

I know of two silent bad codegen bugs that ***might*** be related:

- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800364/initializer-list-calls-object-destructor-twice
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800104/

Honestly I think these are different, though. Does anyone know

1. whether there is an actively tracked bug on connect for this
2. whether there is a workaround (or an explicit description of the situation that causes this bug, so we can look for it/avoid it in our code base)?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Just create an empty project using the C++ Console Application 'wizard'. For simplicity, disable precompiled headers and leave all defaults: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrrnV.png

Comment: `return 0;` is missing but seems not to be related...

Comment: @Mario, not requred. Also not related.

Comment: @Sehe what about https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809243/c-11-initializer-lists-as-default-argument? I don't know if it's relevant or related.

Comment: @remyabel Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you mind posting as an answer (I could add a number of workarounds in case you want), we can have this as the answer.

Comment: Looks like this is a problem in the general case [vc++](http://rextester.com/CLLDLT38952) Vs [clang and gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b73cc04ce95cf0).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks, I wasn't aware of any online compiler capable of vc++, let alone `C++ (vc++) and C - Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86`. Not bad

Comment: @sehe I try to keep [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652386/1708801) entry up to date when I find new resources, have not in a while. If you know of anything I am missing let me know. Rextester also allows for live cooperation which is neat.

Comment: @remyabel what version of `gcc` can you reproduce that on? I can't seem to reproduce on `4.8.1`, maybe a live example would help. What I was referring to though was that `VC++` is calling the wrong constructor in the default argument case, which is weird.

Comment: @Shafik Oh I see, disregard my comment then. I mistook your comment to mean the bug exists in both vc++ and gcc/clang. I was conflating `gcc`'s ICE/destructor issues with vc++ calling the wrong constructor. But apparently it's an orthogonal issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An active issue was posted back in [November](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809243/c-11-initializer-lists-as-default-argument). The sample code posted was:

```
Compile and run following code in VS2013

#include <string>

void f(std::string s = {}) {
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

The bug has been acknowledged by Microsoft.

There doesn't seem to be a work-around posted there. **Edit** Workarounds can easily be based on avoiding the list-initializer syntax:

```
void f(std::string s = "");
void f(std::string s = std::string());
void f(std::string s = std::string {});
```

Or just the old-fashioned (if you don't mind introducing overloads):

```
void f(std::string s);
void f() { f(std::string()); }
```

Comment: I've added the obvious workarounds. This somewhat answers the question what to look for. I guess grepping for `={}` or `{{}`, `,{}` goes some way to finding occurrences of this. I'm not completely reassured that this will find (all) relevant call sites though.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like `Visual Studio` is just broken with respect to which constructor it calls when the default argument is an *initializer list*. This code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
  test ()  { std::cout << "test ()" << std::endl ; } 
  test (int)  { std::cout << "test (int)" << std::endl ; }
};

void func( test const &s = {} )
{
}

int main()
{
    test s = {} ;
    func() ;
}
```

produces this result in `gcc` and `clang`, see it [live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4029f192bc53638):

```
test ()
test ()
```

while `Visual Studio` produces this result:

```
test ()
test (int)
```

and for this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct test {
  test ()  { std::cout << "test ()" << std::endl ; };

  test (int)  { std::cout << "test (int)" << std::endl ; };
  test ( std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << "test (initializer_list<int>)" << std::endl ; } ;
};

void func( test const &s = {0} )
{
}

int main()
{
    test s = {0} ;
    func() ;
}
```

`gcc` and `clang` produce this result see it [live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f51593eadef7ecb5):

```
 test (initializer_list<int>)
 test (initializer_list<int>)
```

while `Visual Studio` produces this error:

```
 error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'const test &'
    Reason: cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'const test'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

**Update**

For a sanity check, I went back to the standard to make sure there wasn't some odd rule at the root of this difference or perhaps some restriction that makes this code *ill-formed*. As far as I can tell this code is not *ill-formed*. Section `8.3.5` grammar specifically allows this:

```
parameter-declaration:
  attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator
  attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
  [...]
```

It does not seem like section `8.5` *Initializers* or `8.3.6` *Default arguments* add any restrictions but this defect report [994. braced-init-list as a default argument](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#994)  and working paper [Wording for brace-initializers as default arguments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3217.htm) make it clear that it was intended and outline the changes made to the standard to allow it and looking at the deltas there are no obvious restrictions.

Comment: I'd comment this over at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809243/c-11-initializer-lists-as-default-argument too, just in case they need any help :/ (Well, perhaps they need help realizing this bug is disruptive)

Comment: @sehe comment added to the bug report