# How can you give a default value for a vector parameter in a function

Tags: c++, vector, default-value

Take the following example code:

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> uint8Vect_t;

void setSomeThing(int value, uint8Vect parameters)
{
    //... do some stuff ...
    if (parameters.size() > 0)
    {
        //... do some stuff with parameters ...
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8Vect intParams;
    intParams.push_back(1);
    intParams.push_back(2);

    // Case 1 - pass parameters
    setSomeThing(1, intParams);

    // Case 2 - pass no parameters, default value should be used
    setSomeThing(1);

    return 0;
}
```

My question here is that I want to set a default value for the vector parameter of the function like this:

```
setSomeThing(int value, uint8Vect parameters = 0)
```

Where if no parameter "parameters" is passed in then an empty vector is used by default. However I can't figure out what the syntax should be - if it is possible. I know I could use an overloaded function, but I want to know how to do this anyway.

Comment: Have you tried `setSomeThing(int value, uint8Vect parameters = 0)`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore err... no, I did not want to because it just seems wrong! :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void setSomeThing(int value, uint8Vect_t parameters = uint8Vect_t()) { .... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling the default constructor will construct an empty vector.

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> uint8Vect_t;
void setSomeThing(int value, uint8Vect_t parameters = uint8Vect_t{})
{
    if (parameters.size() > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This method is better because you can create a custom default vector wit any values you want. But it requires  C++11

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes I was going to say this works fine for c++11, but not c99 - I did not specify which I was using though :)

Comment: @Davidbrcz It is not necessarily "better". Creating a custom size 500 vector with values set to 42 would be quite tedious.

Comment: @Davidbrcz The only difference between mine and juanchopanza's answer is that I fixed some of the typos on op's code.

Comment: If using C++11, even `uint8Vect_t parameters = {}` works the same way.

Comment: @remyabel hang on.... what typos, I am not spotting them :( (EDIT: Actually I think I found it....the missing brackets, sorry).

Comment: @chris keep in mind using `={}` [may be broken is you are using Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044488/known-compiler-bug-in-vc12/21048459#21048459).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, That's a shame.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - ya, I totally do! - I am always switching between c and c++ and I get very confused sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

If using C++11, even `uint8Vect_t parameters = {}` works - [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091674/how-can-you-give-a-default-value-for-a-vector-parameter-in-a-function#comment31726256_21091722) by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris)