# std::map argument with empty brace-initializers for default argument segfaults in GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, default-arguments

## Problem

I got a bug report from user reporting a segfault in library I develop.

The minimal example of the faulty code is:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::map<std::string, std::string> m = {})
{
        std::cout << m.size() << "\n";
        for (const auto& s: m) {
                std::cout << s.first << "->" << s.second <<"\n";
        }
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

When compiled with GCC (I tested 4.8.2 and 4.7.3) it correctly prints `0` as size of the container, but segfaults inside the loop (which shouldn't be executed at all).

## Workarounds

However, I can *fix* the problem by changing the declaration to:

```
void f(std::map<std::string, std::string> m = std::map<std::string, std::string>{})
```

Copying the `map` works as well:

```
void f(std::map<std::string, std::string> mx = {})
{
        auto m = mx;
        std::cout << m.size() << "\n";
        for (const auto& s: m) {
                std::cout << s.first << "->" << s.second <<"\n";
        }
}
```

Changing the parameter to `const std::map<...>&` also works.

GCC 4.9.1 works fine.

Clang also compiles and runs the code just fine. (even when using the same libstdc++ as failing gcc 4.8.2)

*Working* example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb64a7053f542efd

## Question

The map is definitely not in valid state inside the function (details bellow).
It looks like a GCC (or libstdc++) bug, but I want to be sure I'm not making some stupid mistake here. 
It's hard to believe such a bug would stay in gcc for at least 2 major version.

So my question is:  Is the way of initializing default `std::map` parameter wrong (and bug in my code) or is it a bug in `stdlibc++` (or `gcc`)?

I'm not looking for workarounds (as I know what to do to make to code work)
When integrated in the application, the offending code executes fine  on some computers (even when compiled with gcc 4.8.2) on some doesn't.

## Details

I compile it using:

```
g++-4.8.2 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -std=c++11 /tmp/c.cpp -o /tmp/t
```

Backtrace from gdb:

```
#0  std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (__os=..., __str=...) at /usr/src/debug/sys-devel/gcc-4.8.2/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:2758
#1  0x0000000000400f36 in f (m=std::map with 0 elements) at /tmp/c.cpp:9
#2  0x0000000000400fe0 in main () at /tmp/c.cpp:15
```

/tmp/c.cpp:9 is the line with `std::cout << ...`

ASAN reports:

```
AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0xffffffffffffffe8
```

This seems like `nullptr - 8`

valgrind shows:

```
==28183== Invalid read of size 8
==28183==    at 0x4ECC863: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==28183==    by 0x400BD5: f(std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >) (c.cpp:9)
==28183==    by 0x400C7F: main (c.cpp:15)
==28183==  Address 0xffffffffffffffe8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Looking at internal state of the map shows that the code really has to fail:

`std::map::begin()` in libstdc++ returns value of

```
this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent
```

from it's internal representation, `std::map::end()` returns:

```
&this->_M_impl._M_header
```

gdb shows:

```
(gdb) print m._M_t._M_impl._M_header
$5 = {_M_color = std::_S_red, _M_parent = 0x0, _M_left = 0x7fffffffd6d8, _M_right = 0x7fffffffd6d8}
(gdb) print &m._M_t._M_impl._M_header
$6 = (std::_Rb_tree_node_base *) 0x7fffffffd6a8
```

So value of `begin()` and `end()` are not the same (`begin()` is nullptr) as mandated by standard for empty `std::map`.

Comment: FWIW, When I replaced `std::cout << s.first << "->" << s.second <<"\n";` by  `std::cout << "Came here\n";`, the program prints the line once and then hangs.

Comment: "It's hard to believe such a bug would stay in gcc for at least 2 major version." - you must be new here

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like this [bug was fixed in 4.8.3/4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60367), the bug report which has a similar example and also seg-faults says:

> The attached minimal testcase has the following function with
>   default-constructed default argument:
>
> ```
> void do_something( foo f = {} )
> {     std::cout << "default argument is at " << &f << std::endl;
> }
> ```
>
> The constructor for foo outputs its address; I got the following
>   output from a single run:
>       constructed foo @ 0x7ffff10bdb7f
>       default argument is at 0x7ffff10bdb60
>
> It shows that only 1 foo was constructed, and not at the same address
>   as that of the default argument. It's been a loooong week, but I can't
>   see anything wrong with the code. In the real code on which this was
>   based, a segfault was occurring when running the destructor of a foo
>   that was move-constructed from the default argument, because the
>   underlying memory was seemingly uninitialised.

We can see from a [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pHfVahnSgC5tUDLU) that `4.9.0` does not demonstrate this problem.

We can see this was intentional functionality from [defect report 994](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#994) and the subsequent resolution [N3217](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3217.htm):

> This paper presents detailed wording changes relative to the current
>   C++ Working Draft N3126 to implement brace-initializers for default
>   arguments for functions, as proposed in N3139 "An Incomplete Language
>   Feature" by Bjarne Stroustrup, thereby also addressing core issue 994.

This is also covered in the proposal [N3139: An Incomplete Language Feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3139.pdf).

Interesting to note that [Visual Studio also has a bug with respect to brace-initializers as default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21044488/1708801) which I think is still unresolved.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know and couldn't find.