# Why does clang++ destroy only one foo object?

Tags: c++, clang

I have the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    foo()  { cout << "foo constructed.\n"; }
    ~foo() { cout << "foo destroyed.\n"; }
};

struct bar {
    bar(foo t=foo{}) { }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bar X[2]{};
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with clang++ -std=c++11 test.cc, the program produces the following output:

```
foo constructed.
foo constructed.
foo destroyed.
```

but I expected an additional "foo destroyed." between the two "foo constructed." lines. Why is only one foo destroyed? This happens with clang 3.5.1 as well as 3.6.0.

Comment: GCC 4.9 outputs `foo constructed. foo destroyed. foo constructed. foo destroyed.` Clang 3.5 and 3.6 reproduce your results, though. I'm guessing it's a bug in clang (using libstdc++ with clang still produces the erroneous results, so I don't think its a standard library issue).

Comment: Try `endl` instead of `\n`.

Comment: What version of clang? Why does nobody ever write down the @~!#ing version number??

Comment: Ideone [does the same](http://ideone.com/gCIS2S) as GCC 4.9

Comment: @zenith: Streams are flushed when the program ends, bub!

Comment: @wolfPack88: That _is_ GCC 4.9[.2].

Comment: @zenith at termination the paths are closed, and when a path is closed, it gets flushed. This is just the way any sane operating system handles things.

Comment: @zenith: Um the fundamentals of C++? Streams are flushed when they go out of scope, `std::cout` is an object with `static` storage duration, and such objects are destroyed after `main` returns.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thought it was an older version somehow... Either way, I figured I'd provide a link

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough.

Comment: In case no one has tried, replace `[2]` with `[10]` and the results are similar; 10 constructions, but still one destruction. (OS X clang 3.5). Also, test with removing `{}`. That difference one I particularly like.

Comment: Clang with -lstdc++ indeed prints only one destruction. And gdb with breakpoint in destructor ~foo() lands only one time in destructor.

Comment: FWIW, http://goo.gl/fkw6dq

Comment: This is interesting.

Comment: It must be some sort of bug with `{}` because it works without. The program is well-formed.

Comment: In `-O0` the destructor is called twice; in `-O1` and above it is only called once.

Comment: @rwong, the optimization level doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @rwong I concur with @wonderingnewbie. -O0 through -O3 makes no difference on my clang 3.5. Removal or retention of the initializer list `{}` on the array definitely alters behavior (I'm likewise using libc++ for all of this in case anyone cares).

Comment: wonderingnewbie I was using the link provided by chris. The setting was x86 GCC 4.9.2. (To clarify, I'm not implying that it is a lesser issue; I'm just sharing ways to probe around the problem, such as optimization flags and settings to help diagnose the cause. IMHO it does look like a compiler optimization bug.)

Comment: @rwong in `-O0` the destructor is called twice -- but the constructor only once!  In `-O1` both are called once (correct behaviour).  This in Chris's link which goes to clang 3.7

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for all the people who tested it! This seems to be a bug in clang. I'd appreciate if someone reports it to llvm.org. My few bugs reports there were, let say, not really helpful, so I am not looking to repeat that experience.

Comment: Done https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22877 (including turning it into a memory leak that shows up with asan and valgrind)

Comment: I find this questions fascinating since it seems there has been some sort of `{}` initializer issue with all the major compilers with default arguments. For example see [std::map argument with empty brace-initializers for default argument segfaults in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28837142/1708801) and [(Known) compiler bug in VC12?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21044488/1708801).

Comment: @shafik my thoughts exactly. This exact issue turned up in gcc last year! http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60367

Comment: Sad state, Jonathan reported the bug over an year ago and they still haven't fixed it. :(

Comment: I just fixed this in Clang trunk, the fix will be in Clang 5 and should also be in Clang 4.0.1.