# Static const map initialization list with struct?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

Code section:

```
struct id_s {
    std::string name1;
    std::string name2;
};

static const std::map<uint8_t, id_s> list = {
    { 0x00, { "Fred", "Apple" } },
    { 0x01, { "John", "Banana" } },
    { 0x02, { "Mark", "Mango" } }
};

int main()
{
    for(const auto& it: list) {
        std::cout<<it.first<<"\t"<<it.second.name1<<"\t"<<it.second.name2<<std::endl;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Problem is that once initialized all fields are correctly assigned, except "John" and "Mark", which are  left as "".

How to correctly assign this with C++11 initialization lists?

Output from VS 2013 debug console:

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2nqduea.jpg]

Comment: This is the correct way to assign the values using intializer list. Can you show your output(screen shot) from the console?.

Comment: I've added a link to the screenshot, I can't embed as not enough reputation...

Comment: I have validated that this code does indeed behave as described in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 fixes this bug, and it's still good in Update 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 has just fixed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to initialize.I have ran your program and used to print it on console using the following code

```
for(const auto& it: lst) {
 std::cout<<it.first<<"\t"<<it.second.name1<<"\t"<<it.second.name2<<std::endl;
}
```

> Output

```
       Fred    Apple
0x1 John    Banana
0x2 Mark    Mango
```

I ran this program Linux machine. I am using gcc4.8.1 which is fully c++11 compliant.Well I have not used the VS2013 but if you are using it as above and not getting the correct initialized values, there could be problem/bug VS2013 as it may not have complete implementation of initializer list.

BTW you should not use the variable name which has defined in the standard(**list**). This is not a good practice.

**EDIT**

it looks like it is known bug in VS2013 and you can find the relevant information from the following SO post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646517/2724703

Comment: Thanks.  I did suspect it might be a VS2013 problem.

Don't worry, the "list" variable was just used when I quickly created this question here.  :)

Comment: @user3443139:Check out the my edited post. It looks like known bug in VS2013.