# Possible bug in Visual Studio with in-place struct initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Message
{
  std::string to;
  std::string text;
};

void foo(const Message& msg)
{
  std::cout << msg.to << ' ' << msg.text << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> dict;
  dict["bar"] = "baz";

  foo(Message{ dict["bar"], "foobar" });
  foo(Message{ "baz", "foobar" });

  Message msg;
  msg.to = dict["bar"];
  msg.text = "foobar";
  foo(msg);
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
baz foobar
baz foobar
baz foobar
```

However, it seems the Visual Studio 2013 thinks another way:

```
 foobar
baz foobar
baz foobar
```

Why? What's the reason behind this? Is it a bug?

Comment: I just tried it.  It works as you expect on Visual Studio 2015.  What version of VS do you have?

Comment: Works with g++ as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1b5e675e186507f

Comment: @selbie VS2013, I mentioned it in the OP-post

Comment: Let me try on VS2013....

Comment: There's nothing we can do about it. Report it to Connect Feedback or upgrade to VS2015.

Comment: It works fine on VS 2013 as well.  Do you have all the latest updates and patches for VS 2013?  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

Comment: Works for me in VS 2013 Community Edition, on both release and debug.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with my copy of MSVS 2013 Express.  Version 12.0.21005.1 REL.  Updating to update 5 to see if it still exists

Comment: I believe the cause going to be the same as here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19646517/2550156